# Google Maps Android API Removing markers when switching floors

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im working on a Android app project that needs an indoor map. The location I am using has the floors available on Google maps. Im using the Google Maps Android API. I have markers set on the initial level shown. How can I remove/hide these markers and replace them with new one when I switch floors? 
here is my java code:

```
package com.me.maps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Milwaukee, Wisconsin.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng mpm = new LatLng(43.0408468, -87.921474);
        LatLng planetarium = new LatLng(43.040622,-87.920798);
        LatLng theater = new LatLng(43.040497,-87.920640);
        LatLng marketplace = new LatLng(43.040779,-87.921717);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mpm).title("Milwaukee Public Museum"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(planetarium).title("The Daniel M. Soref National Geographic Planetarium"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(theater).title("The Daniel M. Soref National Geographic Theater"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marketplace).title("Museum Marketplace"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mpm, 18));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Place current location marker
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.doctor);
    markerOptions.icon(icon);
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
```

use this code used for change markers icon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure where this goes. I added it to onMapReady() and it showed errors. Is there a certain way to implement this? Does this need to be attached to the floor selector buttons?

Comment: when you click floor selector buttons just clear the created markers using @here, ```markerOptions.clear()```

Answer (score 0):

When you switch floors, your app should clear the markers already on map. Use the .clear() method of the google map instance and then add the markers related to that floor only.

The documentation for this methods can be found at: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap

Hope it Helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding where I attach .clear() to. I'm looking at the documentation and the only reference to the floor selector is: setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true); is their a event listener or something I need to add to my code? I don't know where I'm supposed to look. I don't see any reference to how to add anything to clicking on those specific buttons.